# Superinit issue with Swift

Tags: methods, swift

I'm just getting started with Swift and i got into classes. If I want to have a super class called "Team" and a subclass of "Team" called "Player".

My idea it's to create a team and a player and after add the player to the Array of teamPlayers. But when I create my Player I must re-create a team name. There is no way to override the the init method on the Player Class?

Classes (Player is a subclass of Team):
-- Team
- Player

```
import UIKit

class Team {
    var teamName: String
    var teamPlayers:[Player] = []

    init(aName: String){
        self.teamName = aName
    }

    // methods

    func addPlayer(aPlayer: Player){
        teamPlayers.append(aPlayer)
    }

}

class Player: Team {
    var playerName: String
    var playerNumber: Int

    init(aName: String, aNumber: Int){
        self.playerName = aName
        self.playerNumber = aNumber
        super.init(aName: "Barcelona")
    }
}

var myTeam: Team = Team(aName: "Barcelona")
var lionelMessi: Player = Player(aName: "Lionel Messi", aNumber: 10)
myTeam.addPlayer(lionelMessi)
```

**Update:**

Makes more sense like this, and this is what I was trying to achieve:

```
import UIKit

class Team {
    var teamName: String
    var teamPlayers:[Player] = []

    init(aName: String){
        self.teamName = aName
    }

    // methods
    func addPlayer(aPlayer: Player){
        teamPlayers.append(aPlayer)
    }

    func returnCount() -> Int {
        return self.teamPlayers.count
    }
}

class Player: Team {
    var playerName: String
    var playerNumber: Int

    init(aName: String, aNumber: Int, aTeam: String){

        self.playerName = aName
        self.playerNumber = aNumber
        super.init(aName: aTeam)
    }
}

var myTeam: Team = Team(aName: "Barcelona")
var lionelMessi: Player = Player(aName: "Lionel Messi", aNumber: 10, aTeam: myTeam.teamName)
myTeam.addPlayer(lionelMessi)
var daniAlvez: Player = Player(aName: "Dani Alvez", aNumber: 2, aTeam: myTeam.teamName)
myTeam.addPlayer(daniAlvez)
myTeam.returnCount()
```

Comment: Why is `Player` a subclass of `Team`, anyway?  That doesn't seem to make too much sense.  Anyway, what you're doing *is* overriding the constructor...

Comment: Nevermind,

Fixed with this:


`class Player: Team {
    var playerName: String
    var playerNumber: Int
    
    init(aName: String, aNumber: Int, aTeam: String){
        
        self.playerName = aName
        self.playerNumber = aNumber
        super.init(aName: aTeam)
    }
}

var myTeam: Team = Team(aName: "Barcelona")
var lionelMessi: Player = Player(aName: "Lionel Messi", aNumber: 10, aTeam: myTeam.teamName)

myTeam.addPlayer(lionelMessi)`

Comment: @sapi How would you do it?

Comment: Player should not be a subclass of Team. Teams should have a players collection, and players should have a (probably weak) property for their team. But a player is not a kind of team (which is what you're saying when you inherit this way).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm adding this answer since the poster asked about a cleaner way to accomplish his goals.

@user2321906, this removes the need for inheritance between the two classes and might be a bit more natural to use:

```
class Team {
  var teamName: String

  // strong reference to a Player
  // uses a Dictionary so a number can only have one player
  var teamPlayers:[Int: Player] = [Int: Player]()

  init(name: String){
    self.teamName = name
  }

  // Now it not only adds the player, it also sets the team and the number.
  func addPlayer(player: Player, number: Int){
    player.playerNumber = number
    player.team = self
    teamPlayers[number] = player
  }

  func returnCount() -> Int {
    return self.teamPlayers.count
  }
}

class Player {
  var playerName: String
  var playerNumber: Int?
  var team: Team? // weak reference to a Team

  init(name: String){
    self.playerName = name
  }
}

let myTeam: Team = Team(name: "Barcelona")
let lionelMessi: Player = Player(name: "Lionel Messi")
myTeam.addPlayer(lionelMessi, number: 10)
let daniAlvez: Player = Player(name: "Dani Alvez")
myTeam.addPlayer(daniAlvez, number: 2)
myTeam.returnCount()        // -> 2

lionelMessi.team!.teamName  // -> "Barcelona"
```

Now a Player is assigned a number and team when the Team object adds it. There's no inheritance between the two classes, something that didn't make sense because inheritance is for classes that have a "is-a" relationship. A Player is not a type of Team, instead a Team has a Player so it is a "has-a" relationship.

The other thing is that I prevented a circular reference by having the Team hold a strong reference to a Player but the Player holds a weak reference to a Team. I stored the Team as a reference in the Player so that if data is changed in the Team it will be reflected in the Player automatically, as well as avoiding duplicating the data.

Comment: Thank you very much. Made more sense the way you said it.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't have Player inherit from Team. It doesn't make sense for a player to be a subclass of team. That implies that a Player is a more specific type of Team. You can trim your player class down to this:

```
class Player {
    var playerName: String
    var playerNumber: Int

    init(aName: String, aNumber: Int){
        self.playerName = aName
        self.playerNumber = aNumber
    }
}
```

Team and Player still have a composition relationship, where a Team contains some number of Players along with other information.